# Windows OS has fatal error and I need to install ubuntu instead

Tags: system-installation, usb, backuppc

I am new in ubuntu so a step by step guide will be highly appreciated.
My windows OS laptop crashed with fatal error, it won't even go past the boot.
I need a way to install a new OS (hence ubuntu) and to restore whatever I have on my hard drive C:/

Comment: If you install an OS on your machine, it'll replace whatever exists on your machine, so restoration won't be possible.  You should restore the data you want FIRST, then re-use it via a installation of OS.  I'd normally provide links on how to download, write to media & install Ubuntu - but doing that will overwrite data (making restoration impossible for at least portions, and harder for the rest anyway).  Boot a *live* Ubuntu system (eg. installation media) and backup your data before installation.  Install only when your wanted data is safely backed up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) Select *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows* at the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer.

Comment: Ubuntu is good, but for to fix or find data on Windows, it would be best to try Windows tools first.  There is a good chance that Windows had fast boot on, and Ubuntu will not help much if that is the case.  Would only try with a Ubuntu USB installer, using 'try Ubuntu' and see if Ubuntu can see any data.  Do not install on Windows drive.  Installing Ubuntu will wipe all your data.

Comment: Will probably need another laptop/computer to download any OS USB installer files.  Would try to download Win 10/7 first to try to fix your Windows, then maybe Ubuntu

Comment: Can see this to help.  https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/fatal-error.html

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu provide exactly what you ask for here

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview